# while in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, while-loop

I am making a  bash script. the objective is:
execute a program wait some seconds reset the program and repeat the process. 
I make 2 scripts but i don't know where is the error...

```
 #!/bin/bash
while true; 
do 
seg=`date +%M`;
if [[ "$seg" -eq "30" ]]; 
then killall sox;
echo "reset"; 
fi
done
```

bash: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `;'

```
#!/bin/bash
while true;
do
nice -n-10 sox -q -V0 --multi-threaded -t alsa hw:2,0 -t alsa pcm.default && 
done
```

bash: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `done'

Comment: What's the intention of the second script?  Start a new `sox` process if the old one dies?  Just lose the `&&`  then.

Comment: Many of us here have no idea what "sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado" means... Don't make us guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issues with Script #1:**

The `;` notation is to run multiple commands on the same line, one after another. Bash syntax requires that `while` and `do` on separate lines (same with `if ...` and `then`, and separated by `;` if on the same line. Command statements are not normally terminated with a `;` char in bash.

Change your code from:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; 
do 
seg=`date +%M`;
if [[ "$seg" -eq "30" ]]; 
then killall sox;
echo "reset"; 
fi
done
```

To:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do 
    seg=`date +%M`
    if [[ "$seg" -eq "30" ]]; then
        killall sox
        echo "reset"
    fi
done
```

---

**Issues with Script #2:**

`&` means to run the command as a background process. `&&` is used for conditional command chaining, as in: "If the previous command before `&&` succeeds, then run the next command after the `&&`"

Change from:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true;
do
nice -n-10 sox -q -V0 --multi-threaded -t alsa hw:2,0 -t alsa pcm.default && 
done
```

To:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    nice -n-10 sox -q -V0 --multi-threaded -t alsa hw:2,0 -t alsa pcm.default &
done
```

Comment: thanks.  there are no syntax error on second script but is not working properly.

Comment: you probably wanted `&`, not `&&`

Comment: Actually, you probably don't want `&`.  That would flood the system with background `sox` processes.